# How to solve the error that exe installer is not a valid win32 application in wix?

Tags: winapi, wix

An exe installer, which was produced using wix v3.8, is not installing on windows xp system. The error is showing that the exe installer is not a valid win32 application. How can I solve this problem? Thanks!

Comment: As far as I know, WiX 3.8 hasn't been released...

Answer (score 1):

This was a bug in the WiX toolset build process where the `vs110_xp` platform was not used to build executables that run correctly on XP from VS2012. That bug was fixed in WiX v3.8.326.0 or later.